# Problems with python easy install

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, easy-install, matplotlib-venn

I have a problem using easy_install for matplotlib-venn. I'm on a windows computer using python2.7.
I'm suspecting the path is not correct but I do not know how to fix the problem.
Could anyone help me?
I'm attaching the output from trying to run the easy_install command in the CMD prompter.

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>easy_install matplotlib-venn
Searching for matplotlib-venn
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib-venn/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib-venn/: [Errno 11004]
 getaddrinfo failed -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'matplotlib-venn' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo fai
led -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for matplotlib-venn
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('matplotlib-ve
nn')
install for matplotlib-venn package
```

---

Output from trying the pip install suggestion:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>easy_install pip
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 1.4.1
Adding pip 1.4.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip-script.py script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Installing pip.exe script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Installing pip.exe.manifest script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Installing pip-2.7-script.py script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Installing pip-2.7.exe script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Installing pip-2.7.exe.manifest script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install matplotlib-venn
Downloading/unpacking matplotlib-venn
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement matplotlib-venn
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for matplotlib-venn
Storing complete log in C:\Users\jherman8\pip\pip.log
```

Comment: This is very strange. If you go to link address which you give log output you can find there `matplotlib-venn`. you sure that there is no encoding problems in your input name? https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib-venn/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on

```
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib-venn/: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

and

```
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

it seems that your have network issue. Do you run your machine behind a firewall or a proxy?

For `easy_install` to work behind proxy, you have to setup needed environments, for example

```
set http_proxy="user:password@server:port"
set https_proxy="user:password@server:port"
```

For pip you can use `-proxy` argument. More details on pip usage behind proxy see in this thread: [How to use pip on windows behind an authenticating proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11869484/1265154)

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out. However I have never performed this type of setup before so I dont now how to do it. Do you have any step by step instructions for a novice like me?

Comment: @jonas for pip, see link in my answer. how to setup env variable in win is described [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Comment: Ok, which path should I put in?

Comment: @jonas not path, you should set http_proxy variable for easy_install. Value depends on your proxy configuration

Comment: sorry, I was using the link with step by step instructions you send me..I'll try again

Answer (score 2):

I think this is your solution

```
easy_install pip
pip install matplotlib-venn
```

No module `matplotlib-venn` in easy_install

And for future, use pip for install any package for python.

Comment: Tried it and pip installation went fine but not th matplolib-venn, se output above

Comment: Hm, you mean that you find it, but it can't install? You run your terminal as root? In linux I install it from `sudo`.

Comment: just installed `matplotlib-venn` with `easy_install`

Answer (score 0):

```
student@student-WIV68105-0080:~$ **sudo apt-cache search rtree**
libcneartree-dev - Library and headers for solving the Nearest Neighbor Problem
libcneartree5 - Library for solving the Nearest Neighbor Problem
student@student-WIV68105-0080:~$ **sudo apt-get install libcneartree-dev libcneartree5**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libcvector2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcneartree-dev libcneartree5 libcvector2
```

For me the same error occurred for rtree package  and I did the cache search and installed the liraries

Answer (score 0):

In-case of cloudera box if you are trying then this will work as reaised in bugzile.
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1510444
It works for my cloudera vm jut follow the insteruction and then try to isntall by easy_install.

# easy_install -i https://pypi.python.org/simple stitches Searching for stitches Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/stitches/ Best match: stitches 0.11 Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/9d/73/681005f0f0fb9483f0d94547a35059c776144fc998780b9ef00167a50f3d/stitches-0.11.tar.gz#md5=0ac0b6e418767e6ec5cf684460d1972f Processing stitches-0.11.tar.gz Running stitches-0.11/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-ZMIU8w/stitches-0.11/egg-dist-tmp-82ctsZ zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents... stitches.connection: module references **file** Adding stitches 0.11 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/stitches-0.11-py2.6.egg Processing dependencies for stitches ... ... Searching for pynacl>=1.0.1 Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pynacl/ Best match: PyNaCl 1.2.0 Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/fa/38/0f35ec4beb6562f1abfa07914db1cea978e93da409ba6293f810d9e677d6/PyNaCl-1.2.0.tar.gz#md5=7a31e95f5f457184b1660b71d6808b19 Processing PyNaCl-1.2.0.tar.gz Running PyNaCl-1.2.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-a0vNJS/PyNaCl-1.2.0/egg-dist-tmp-QYvAk9 Checking .pth file support in . /usr/bin/python -E -c pass Searching for cffi>=1.4.1 Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/ Couldn't find index page for 'cffi' (maybe misspelled?) Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while) Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/ No local packages or download links found for cffi>=1.4.1 error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('cffi>=1.4.1')

So the only solution is hacking the source code:

## sed -i s,http://pypi.python.org,https://pypi.python.org, /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py

sudo