# How do you login to the internet in a python script?

Tags: python, proxy, pip, pycharm

I am trying to connect to the internet with my python script but the proxy requires a username and password. I have both of these, but I do not know how to sign into the proxy during the code.

The response to me trying to connect without a password is this;

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'matplotlib.pyplot'])
Collecting matplotlib.pyplot
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/matplotlib-pyplot/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/matplotlib-pyplot/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/matplotlib-pyplot/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/matplotlib-pyplot/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/matplotlib-pyplot/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib.pyplot (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for matplotlib.pyplot
Out[3]: 1
```

I can elaborate on anything if need be.
Thanks.

Just saying, this is on a school internet system (NSW) so there may be actions that are restricted.

Followed bastelflp's instructions and got this result;
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/euanoflynn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/Users/euanoflynn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 83, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Users/euanoflynn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/euanoflynn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/Users/euanoflynn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 810, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/euanoflynn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 284, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Users/euanoflynn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x118900908>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/euanoflynn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 438, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Users/euanoflynn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 649, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/euanoflynn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='finance.yahoo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x118900908>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out',)))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/euanoflynn/anaconda/tests/Tests.py", line 22, in <module>
    r = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com", proxies=proxies)
  File "/Users/euanoflynn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/euanoflynn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/euanoflynn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 518, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/euanoflynn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 639, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/euanoflynn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 500, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='finance.yahoo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x118900908>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out',)))`

Comment: are you trying to install matplotlib?

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to install matplotlib

Comment: @EleshNorn Why are your using pip from inside a Python script and not directly from the command line? Have a look at [Using pip behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14149422/5276734).

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but... what does this mean in basic (2 months) pythonspeak?

Comment: 2 months of learning python, that is.

Answer (score 0):

Pip install library requests. Use requests to post login event. Keep the session and cookies and you can send new request just like you are login-ed.

Comment: I'm pretty new... how do you post the login event? Had a look at [link] (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) but couldn't understand

Comment: Use chrome, enter develop mode, login the website and find out params send to the website server while login. Then try to send the same data using requests module.

Comment: params meaning parameters?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to **install Python packages**, try using  pip directly from the command line, i.e.

```
pip --proxy your_proxy:port matplotlib
```

with `your_proxy:port` beeing your proxy, e.g. `proxy.example.com:8080`. You can add authentication with the following syntax: `user:password@your_proxy:port`. If you have special characters in your user or password, you may have to escape them. More options for pip behind a proxy can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9698557/5276734).

---

If you want to **access the Internet via Python**, use the Python package [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), which can also [handle proxies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies):

```
import requests

proxies = {
  "http": "your_proxy:port",
  "https": "your_proxy:port",
}

r = requests.get("http://example.org", proxies=proxies)
r.status_code
```

You can find a more detailed explanation on requests with proxies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8287752/5276734).

Comment: Well, this has helped; the program can overcome the proxy. The problem, though, is that it says the host is down even though I can connect to the internet just fine (I am writing this at the same time as the program says the host was down, from the same place). This is a NSW school internet, though, so some actions might be restricted.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the school internet factor.

Comment: `File "/Users/euanoflynn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 500, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.181.157.13', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: http://finance.yahoo.com/ (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10eefd1d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 64] Host is down',)))`

Comment: `File "/Users/euanoflynn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 500, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='finance.yahoo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10e832c18>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out',)))`