# SSL Issue while installing any package using pip behind the proxy

Tags: python, ssl, proxy, pip, http-proxy

Facing issues while installing tensorflow or any other package behind the proxy :

First try :

Run the command :

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Output :

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was
 forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/tensorflow/
```

Second try :

Then I provided the proxy details along with the command

```
>pip install --upgrade tensorflow --proxy http://user:passwd@xxx.xx.x.xx:80
```

Output error :

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:83
3)'),)': /simple/tensorflow/
```

Third try as suggested on [pip install fails with "connection error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi):

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --proxy http://user:passwd@xxx.xx.x.xx:80
```

Output :

Same as above.

Can anyone help ??

edit : working on windows machine

Comment: This doesn't look like a tensorflow specific issue. Can you pip install any other packages? `pip install numpy` for example?

Comment: No this is not specific to tensorflow , I cannot install any package

Comment: Are you behind corporate firewall, eg. Fortinet? They often do nasty things with SSL certificates, kind of MITM.

Comment: Yes, behind the firewall

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that you might need to set your proxy environment variables on your machine to use your proxy. Try setting the following (assumming your on a Linux or Mac OS):

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://user:passwd@xxx.xx.x.xx:80
export HTTPS_PROXY=https://user:passwd@xxx.xx.x.xx:443
```

You don't necessarily need to set the `HTTPS_PROXY` variable but it can't hurt to do so

Then try running without the flags

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Comment: Tried that but getting the same SSL certificate issue.

Comment: Do you get any errors if you run this command? `openssl s_client -connect google.com:443`

Comment: Are you sure you don't have it? I have `openssl` on my windows machine. Otherwise I'm pretty sure it comes installed with Git Bash.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after some update mix-ups between pip and apt. Following the suggestions on some SO page that I don't recall I've launched

```
sudo python -m easy_install --upgrade pyOpenSSL
```

and got the things running again.

LE: might've misread the problem.

Comment: Getting error : Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it -- Some packages may not be found!

Comment: You're hitting the proxy "wall" again ... I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698557/how-to-use-pip-on-windows-behind-an-authenticating-proxy) that might help on making pip work under a proxy in windows, but I would also advise to pull out your phone, enable tethering and pull the stuff you need from internet avoiding the hassle :).