# Disable SSL Certificate verification in Python Google Sheet quickstart

Tags: ssl, google-sheets, google-oauth, google-api-client

I was going through a Google tutorial to connect Google Sheets with python [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python). I am running this piece of code behind a corporate proxy, therefore the certificates received are already replaced by the proxy server.
I have created `token.pickle` file on a non-proxy machine and transferred it here. I get certificate verification failure at this line of the code given in the guide:
`service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)`

The error that comes up is:

```
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)
```

I dig out into the build method [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-module.html). Upon searching through the source codes, I found out that creds and http object as parameters to this method are mutually exclusive, I.e. when I pass `creds` object, I can't pass a `http` object to this function.
If I could pass a `httplib2.http` object, I would have set it to disable SSL verification. But now with this wrapper around, I cannot find any way out to specify this.

I tried the following two hacks also:

1. Creating a unverified context:
   `ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context`
2. Setting `PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0`  as a env variable

But none of them works.
I have my corporate proxy certificate installed in my ca-bundle, and the .cer file too.

Comment: I believe you will need to work with your network administrator to allow a SSL bypass for the authorization as [shown in this Github thread](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5591#issuecomment-406323387). I also found [this answer useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51078072/12835757). Let me know if any of these two options did the trick :D