# pip installation failed : I tried installing pip for python 3.7 software in windows 10 . Running the pip file is giving me an authentication error

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I tried installing pip in python 3.7, windows10.  I downloaded the pip file from the official website and tried installing it.  It is giving the error message as follow:

---

```
Collecting pip
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'))': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'))': /simple/pip/
```

What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use pip on windows behind an authenticating proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698557/how-to-use-pip-on-windows-behind-an-authenticating-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with running python on windows really, but I've heard good things about python in visual studio code. I would expect the installation to be a pretty smooth experience then.

Here is a tutorial to get you started;

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

However it looks like you're behind a authentication proxy. If that makes sense it's probably worth while to check out a previously answered question;

[How to use pip on windows behind an authenticating proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698557/how-to-use-pip-on-windows-behind-an-authenticating-proxy)

Best of luck!