# How to setup `pip` on Windows behind a proxy, without your password in plaintext?

Tags: python, security, pip, proxy, vpn

How do you setup `pip` on a Windows computer that is behind a VPN proxy?

**I've seen 3-4 different options such as**:

1. [Set the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` env variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41957788/10426490)
2. [Create a `pip.ini` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37219624/10426490)
3. [Use CNTLM program(?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11869484/10426490)

- Etc.

Suggestion 1 and 2 above require your password to be typed in plaintext. The password is visible in either the terminal history or the `pip.ini` file which is unacceptable in my case.

Suggestion 3 involves a program I wouldn't install.

So how are those concerned with security setting up `pip` to work behind a VPN?

Comment: I have the exact same problem but on Linux (it is in fact not Windows specific) and I think the answer is: we're scr*ed!