# Use pip with authentication via a proxy server without storing the password as plaintext

Tags: python, pip

I am currently using a machine within an organization that requires passing through a proxy with authentication. I am running Red Hat 7 and need to use pip. However, it seems that the only ways to use pip through a proxy with authentication involve storing the password as plaintext in the config file or an environmental variable, which is really unsafe.

Is there a more secure solution available? I have come across [a similar post for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76075175/7758765), but unfortunately, it doesn't provide any solutions.

Comment: Since `pip` needs to have access to the plain text password and, now the best part, the password is send in clear to most proxies, your effort in storing the password safely will be eaten up by other insecurities.

Comment: Well I see your point but at least it only "pass" and will not be stored in a config file or a bash history